# EnumServicesStatus pascal declare

Tags: dll, windows-services, pascal

I am calling the *EnumServicesStatus* function in pascal.But how to declare it.
here is a example for *OpenSCManager*

```
function OpenSCManager(lpMachineName, lpDatabaseName: string; dwDesiredAccess :cardinal): HANDLE;
external 'OpenSCManagerA@advapi32.dll stdcall';
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like someone has already done the hard work of putting together an entire API .pas file that you can consume. Check out:

http://gr32ex.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/GR32Ex/Examples/DesktopSnow/GPSysHook/api/JwaWinSvc.pas

Search for `EnumServicesStatusA` or `EnumServicesStatusW`; both ANSI and Unicode are there. You'll probably find a variety of structs, enums, and other goodies that you can grab.

Just in case the URL of that file changes, the lines from it that are pertinent, are:

```
function EnumServicesStatusA(hSCManager: SC_HANDLE; dwServiceType: DWORD;
  dwServiceState: DWORD; lpServices: LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUSA; cbBufSize: DWORD;
  var pcbBytesNeeded, lpServicesReturned, lpResumeHandle: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
{$EXTERNALSYM EnumServicesStatusA}

function EnumServicesStatusW(hSCManager: SC_HANDLE; dwServiceType: DWORD;
  dwServiceState: DWORD; lpServices: LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUSW; cbBufSize: DWORD;
  var pcbBytesNeeded, lpServicesReturned, lpResumeHandle: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
{$EXTERNALSYM EnumServicesStatusW}

function EnumServicesStatus(hSCManager: SC_HANDLE; dwServiceType: DWORD;
  dwServiceState: DWORD; lpServices: LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS; cbBufSize: DWORD;
  var pcbBytesNeeded, lpServicesReturned, lpResumeHandle: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
{$EXTERNALSYM EnumServicesStatus}
```

Comment: With the note that $externalsym is not part of the Pascal interface, but for usage from BCB of the same code. If the compiler is Free Pascal, it comes with jwawinsvc out of the box.

Comment: I have tried it this morning and it work well .Thanks for everyone.